# libxml2 in python edit of a specific node

Tags: python, xml, libxml2

I use python with libxml2 for a webapplication.
I need to add an xml node child of one of the articles to an xml with this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archive>
   <article>text<span>tag</span></article>
   <article>text2<span>tag2</span></article>
   <article>text3<span>tag3</span></article>
</archive>
```

The result must be something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <archive>
    <article>text<span>tag</span></article>
    <article>text2<span>tag2</span><counter count='1'/></article>
    <article>text3<span>tag3</span></article>
 </archive>
```

Sorry for the bad english

edit: the webclient will specify when a i need to add the counter node.
my problem is that i can't found the way to select the node i need to modify.
i can modify an xml document adding a child the root element i haven't found a way to do that in elements other than the root element

Comment: 1. What's the rule for adding a counter 2. What have you tried?

Comment: i need to add a counter when i recive a request from the client (the client specify witch post i need to modify) and there is no counter(if there is i need to raise the counter). i can't found a good documentation for libxml2 and python(i tried xpath, but it's return a list of elements not pointers to the xml)

Comment: Try LXML, http://lxml.de

Comment: sadly i can't. i don't have control of the system where i need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you can narrow down the XPath results to a single node then this code will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import libxml2

doc = libxml2.parseFile("foo.xml")

nodes=doc.xpathEval('/archive/article[2]')
newElement = nodes[0].newChild(None, 'counter', None)
newElement.newProp('count', '1')
print nodes[0].serialize()

doc.freeDoc()
```